# CSS dropdown menu, float reset doesn't work, why?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a css dropdown menu using a 'float: none;' in order to make the submenu li's displayed in the actual default list format. But, for some reason, it doesn't work as expected, so I've decided to submit you the code so that maybe you can explain it to me. Thanks in advance.

Here is the HTML:

```
    <div class="top_menu">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a> </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Habits</a>
                <ul class="sub_menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Femme </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Homme </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Enfant </a></li>
                </ul>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Déco </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Liste </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

And now the CSS:

```
.top_menu ul {

list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.top_menu ul li {

float: left;
}

.sub_menu li {

float: none;
}
```

Comment: Not 100%, sure what you are trying to do here, maybe you could create a fiddle?

Shot in the dark, set .sub_menu li  to display: block.

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work as expected"?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, by "doesn't work as expected", I mean the float reset doesn't apply to the sub_menu li's at all, don't know why. ...

Comment: Ok, I just set the sub_menu li's to display:block; and nothing changed at all :/ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with selector precedence.  Both selectors match the leaf list items, but `.top_menu ul li` has higher precedence than `.sub_menu li` because it contains more path steps.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
.top_menu > ul > li {
    float: left;
}
```

then you can style `.sub_menu li` as you please.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this may work for you.

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2fHA/)**

In your original CSS your styles for `.top_menu` were effecting all `li` child elements. You want to use the `>` selector to make sure you're only applying the float to the `top_menu` li elements

CSS:

```
.top_menu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
```